# A/B testing use case and test set up

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design

Suppose I want to know whether a change to a website (such as changing the way the homepage looks) has **no** effect on a metric I care about, such as conversion. Can a frequentist (not Bayesian) A/B test be used for this? If so, how would you set up the test? If not, why not?

Comment: Trivial, you just use a test, the test depends on what you are comparing.